# How to find a path of true values connecting the borders of a 2D array of false values

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to traverse a 2D array of boolean values, from top border to bottom border, and determine a path made entirely of `true` values. At this point, I have tried many different techniques, but I haven't made any progress. Could anyone help me out here?

Here's an example:

```
false true  true  false false false
false true  false false false false
false true  true  false false false
false false true  false false false
```

I need to find a way to determine the `true` value along the borders, then find a way to traverse the path of `true` values.

```
#..###
#.####
#..###
##.###
```

I have begun with algorithms at this point. I have thought of traversing the columns and searching for a `true` value, incrementing the rows by one and then searching the last row, but I don't know how to go about the first and last columns.

The first part to the problem is determining the location of a `true` value along the border. The second part is finding the path of the `true` values and recording their coordinates.

Comment: can you please show, what you have tried?

Comment: @user1810925 What is `true` and `false` in your example?

Comment: I have begun with algorithms at this point , I am trying to determine a way to find out how to go about this really . I have thought of trvaersing through the columns and searching for a true value , increment the rows by one , and then searching the last row , but i dont know how to go about the first and last columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking for. Do you need to just search a 2D array of booleans and return the location of any instance of "true" in a first or last row or column, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: The first part to the problem is determining the location of the true value along the border, the second part is finding the path of the true values and recording their coordinates.

Comment: You need a [Maze solving algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm).

Comment: do you need to find a connected way for all `true` or is it enough to find any way from (in this case) top border to bottom border?

Comment: I edited the diagram . What is needed is a connected path of true's . Sorry about that from top to bottom .

Comment: See section 9.4.1 on this [link](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes6/c9/s1.html), this may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be solved through a simple trial and error algorithm. The top-to-bottom requirement is nice because you know you have to start on the top row of the array, so all you have to do is search that one row for `true` values to start off.

Once you find a `true`, look at its neighboring cells. (Exactly which neighboring cells depends on whether diagonals count and whether your path can bend back upwards like the trap pipes under a sink.)

[image]

(image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vattenlaas.png))

If you find another cell containing `true`, then that cell becomes your "current" cell, and you look at *its* neighbors. Keep doing this until you reach a `true` cell in the last row. Or, if you don't find any `true` neighbors, then go back up to the previous cell and continue with its neighbors.

One way of doing this uses recursion and very little code. Just do something like

```
// pseudocode only
for(Cell foo : all cells in top row)
    checkCell(foo);

boolean checkCell(Cell current) {
    if(current == false)
        return false;

    if(current == true && current.isInLastRow == true)
        return true;

    // if we reach here, the cell is true but we're not done
    for(Cell foo : all valid neighbors of this cell except the "parent")
        return checkCell(foo);
}
```

Another way uses more memory, but is also more efficient. Create a second array, of the same size as the original. When you test a cell from the original array, mark its corresponding cell in the new array. Then, when you're testing neighbors, check the new array to see if you've already been to a given neighbor. If you have, skip it, because it can't lead to success (you know this because you would have already completed and returned if it could). This could save you a lot of time if the array contains a lot of `true` values next to each other, like

```
F T T T F
F T T T F
F T T T F
F T T T F
F T T T F
```

EDIT:
I missed your update comment that says you need to record the coordinates of the cells in the path. No problem: just create a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) of [`Point` objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) recording where you've been. If you ever end up going down a wrong path, just pop once from the stack every time you go "back up a level."

Comment: The problem is ,Torgamus , is that im a beginner in Java , so I am not familiar with objects yet. Is there another fix for this ?

Comment: @user1810925 oh, hmm. I see where you're coming from -- I remember being new and confused -- but I'm not sure what I can say that would be helpful. Objects are pretty much the most fundamental concept in Java, so you're really not going to be able to do much of anything if you don't use them, even if you do manage to solve this problem. I'll think about it.

Comment: Alright thanks and one last quesion ; is there a way to manipulate the for loop to check the columns for true values , because there is also a exception that these true values could go from side to side as well .

Comment: The algorithm doesn't really use any objects except to store the path it took. What format are you supposed to be returning the recorded coordinates in? As for the left-to-right, sure, you'd just use leftmost column instead of top row and rightmost column instead of bottom row.

Comment: Oh, okay, so then, instead of using a stack, and worrying about pushes and pops, just add to or delete from the integer array.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it into a graph and run a path finding algorithm.

Turn every matrix entry into a node on the graph. for each `true` node positioned at `[i,j]` of matrix, connect it to every one of the closest four neighbor entries with `true` values, i.e., the entries at `[i+/-1, j]` and `[i, j+/-1]` whenever such an entry is true. These are all and only edges on the graph. Then run Dijkstra algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm on all `true` nodes positioned at top border. Returns you the shortest path between each `true` node pair whenever there is such a path.